# How to calculate similarity of two lists in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, list, sorting

I have a master list with 8 items in, then a number of lists with the same items as the master list but where the items appear in a different order. How do I find a percentage similarity between each list with the master list?

For example, the master list might be:

*[8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1];*

One of the lists I want to compare it against could be:

*[8,6,4,2,7,5,3,1];*

I know I could just loop through the master list and check for matches, but is there an elegant way to work out how close each number is in the list to the same number in the master list?

For example:

*position 0: '8' match in position 0; 0 positions difference (100%)
position 1: '7' match in position 4; 3 positions difference (57.1%)
position 2: '6' match in position 1; 2 positions difference (71.4%)*

etc.

The end result would be a percentage similarity between the two lists.

Comment: It sounds like you want to find the [edit distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the Array `map` and `reduce` functions:

```
function getSimilaritry(a, b) {
  return a.map(function(val, index) { 
    //calculate the position offset and divide by the length to get each 
    //values similarity score
    var posOffset = Math.abs(b.indexOf(val) - index); 
    return posOffset/a.length
  }).reduce(function(curr, prev) {
    //divide the current value by the length and subtract from 
    //one to get the contribution to similarity 
    return (1 - curr/a.length) + prev;
  });
}
```

If the lists aren't guaranteed to have the same values, you would need to add handling for that.

Also note that the order you pass the arguments `a` and `b` to the `getSimilarity` function will impact the result. Not clear if this is an issue for your application.

PS: I think your question was down-voted for not including the code you already had trying to solve this problem.